# No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, entitymanager

No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call

when I do a test with JUnit, persist method works and I see that my object is inserted, but when I call the method via my Controller doesn't work

here is my Project :

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd">



<!--    <bean id="notification" class="com.app.sqli.notification.NotificationTask" /> -->

<!--    <task:scheduled-tasks> -->
<!--        <task:scheduled ref="notification" method="notifier" cron="*/2 * * * * *"/> -->
<!--    </task:scheduled-tasks> -->

<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.sqli" />  

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
       <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.app.sqli.entities" />
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
      </property>
      <property name="jpaProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>


   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqli" />
      <property name="username" value="root" />
      <property name="password" value="" />
   </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
   </bean>


   <tx:annotation-driven />


</beans>
```

my Model Class:

```
package com.app.sqli.models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Collaborateur {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String nom;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

}
```

my DAO Class

```
package com.app.sqli.dao;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.app.sqli.models.Collaborateur;

@Repository
public class CollaborateurDao implements IcollaborateurDao{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void addCollaborateur(Collaborateur c) {
    em.persist(c);

    }

}
```

My Service Class

```
package com.app.sqli.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.app.sqli.dao.IcollaborateurDao;
import com.app.sqli.models.Collaborateur;

@Service
@Transactional
public class CollaborateurService implements IcollaborateurService{

    @Autowired
    private IcollaborateurDao cdao;

    @Override
    public void addCollaborateur(Collaborateur c) {
        cdao.addCollaborateur(c);

    }


}
```

And My Controller

```
package com.app.sqli.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.app.sqli.models.Collaborateur;
import com.app.sqli.services.IcollaborateurService;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    private IcollaborateurService cserv;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
    public String index(Model m) {
        System.out.println("insertion ...");
        Collaborateur c = new Collaborateur();
        c.setId(11);
        c.setNom("nom");
        cserv.addCollaborateur(c);
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting? Without knowing the exception the only thing i can think of is using the PersistenceContextType.Extended on your EM. @PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
 EntityManager em;

Comment: the Error I'am getting :   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call

Comment: Did you try with PersistanceContextType.Extended? In a nutshell, this changes from transaction-scope EM to a stateful session bean...

Comment: it seams to be solved, Now i have this error message :    Unknown entity: com.app.sqli.models.Collaborateur

Comment: PackagesToScan says that your entities should be in this package com.app.sqli.entities but your entity is in: com.app.sqli.models... They have to match so move your entity to the correct package or change packagesToScan to match the package of your entities

Comment: thank you so much Mr @Mechkov you saved my entire life, the only thing that I need to know is what is the difference between extended persistence context and Transaction which is set by default

Comment: now my project works without any Exception, but my object is not inserted in my database

Comment: In a nutshell, Extended uses EM as a stateful session bean, while Transactional(the default) ends with a rollback/commit.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: i get no exception, i think i have to add commit method but i dont know how

Comment: Persist should commit internally, or you can try em.flush() to explicitly do it...

Comment: now i getan exception with this message, in method flush() :no transaction is in progress    ... is there a way to mae normal EntityManager work ??

Comment: You can open and close transaction manually, but this is not recommended. Instead you should have Spring manage the transactional state of your persistence context. In case you want to try manually, you can open transaction like :entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist( new Event( "Our very first event!", new Date() ) );
entityManager.persist( new Event( "A follow up event", new Date() ) );
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
entityManager.close();

Comment: I highly discourage you to manually handle your Transaction management as i described above.

Comment: yes I've tried this but, it is not recommended as you said, and my project wont be accepted if use this process

Comment: Let me guess you have a `dispatcher-servlet.xml` (or the like) which also contains `<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.sqli" />`... Leading to 2 instances of the service 1 transactional (and not used) and one not transactional (the one used).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

thank you @mechkov for your time and help,
My problem is resolved by changing my configuration file, so I have used a Configuration Class with annotations and its works so fine, I still Don't know where the problem was

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "your package")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class DatabaseConfig {

        protected static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        protected static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "password";
        protected static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename";
        protected static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "login";

        private static final String PROPERTY_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "where your models are";
        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter){
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(PROPERTY_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
            return entityManagerFactoryBean;
        }

        @Bean
        public BasicDataSource dataSource(){
            BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
            ds.setDriverClassName(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER);
            ds.setUrl(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL);
            ds.setUsername(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME);
            ds.setPassword(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD);
            ds.setInitialSize(5);
            return ds;
        }

        @Bean
        public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
            adapter.setShowSql(true);
            adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

//I'm using MySQL5InnoDBDialect to make my tables support foreign keys
adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
            return adapter;
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
        }


    }
```

Comment: I got the same exception and I'm using annotation from the start. I solved the problem by adding the @EnableTransactionManagement from this example. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, same here (needing @EnableTransactionManagement) but also I gleaned a nugget from this answer - a better set up for my beans - I was providing the setters of LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean for dataSource and jpaVendorAdapter with calls to the defined bean methods!I'm guessing that's against the grain of container management and unsure of the side effects but I righted everything after reading this and my problems went away :D

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if anyone who is reading this (today) has the same case as mine, but I had the same problem. Luckly, I could fix it by simply putting the following in my spring-conf.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
...
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
...
xsi:schemaLocation="
...
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<bean id="tManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
</bean>

<!-- This does the trick! -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="tManager" />
```

**Note:** I'm using declarative transactions through annotations. So, if you do, annotating your method with [@Transactional](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained) can also solve your problem.

**REFERENCE:**

1. http://blog.jhades.org/how-does-spring-transactional-really-work/
2. http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm, that adding last bean definition solves this issue !

My config class is as below :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan
public class OFSConfig {

    @Bean
    public IDAO<FuelStation> getFSService() {
        return new FSService();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean() {
        LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean e = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        e.setPersistenceUnitName("org.superbapps.db_OWSDB_PU");

        return e;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory em) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(em);
    }
}
```

The service itself is as follows :

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class FSService implements IDAO<FuelStation> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager EM;

    public EntityManager getEM() {
        return EM;
    }

    public void setEM(EntityManager EM) {
        this.EM = EM;
    }

    @Override
    public List<FuelStation> getAll() {
        return EM.createNamedQuery("FuelStation.findAll")
                .getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public FuelStation getByID(String ID) {
        FuelStation fs = (FuelStation) EM.createNamedQuery("FuelStation.findById")
                .setParameter("id", ID)
                .getSingleResult();

        return fs;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(FuelStation entity) {
        EM.merge(entity);
    }

}
```